# How can I download subtitles for a Vimeo video?

Tags: download, video-streaming, subtitles, vimeo

I've been able to rip a Vimeo video with a Firefox extension.

But what about captions?

It seems they are not easy to download.

Answer (score 3):

Found answer at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27886440/1548085) (the only difference was `*.vtt` instead of `*.srt`):

> To get any file downloaded by an swf loaded with by a html page, you
>   can use your browser developer tool and look on the Network log (
>   chrome in my case ):
>   [image: screen shot]

Comment: Vimeo seems to have .vtt files now.

Answer (score 1):

You can access captions through the Vimeo API. The [Text Track endpoints](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#/%7Bvideo_id%7D/texttracks) allow you to retrieve direct links to the caption files.

Comment: how do I download the subtitles from https://vimeo.com/ondemand/214953675? Can you please add an example? https://api.vimeo.com/videos/214953675/texttracks does not work. Thank you.

Comment: @LeeBinder you can follow the steps I described in this gist in order to download subtitles/captions/texttracks of on-demand videos in Vimeo: https://gist.github.com/pjmartorell/384aa1d019f919af6b84894038bf29aa

I hope it helps :)